# Enable Postgis extension Postgres in Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

How can i enable the Postgis extension in a Dockerfile? The Postgres installation is already working

this is the command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update -y

################## BEGIN INSTALLATION ######################
# Postgres with Postgis
# Install wget
RUN apt-get install wget -y

# Setup Postgres repository
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Add Postgres repository
RUN sh -c "echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list"

# Update repository
RUN apt-get update -y

# Install Postgres with Postgis
RUN apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 -y

# Change rights for start Postgresql
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/postgresql

# Start Postgresql
CMD service postgresql start && tail -F /var/lib/postgresql/data/serverlog
```

Comment: Did you try this: `RUN psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"`? 
If yes and it didnt' help, then can you show us a Dockerfile you are using?

Comment: if i try:      RUN psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" . I'm getting this error:      psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 4):

The solution for enable an extension

```
# Enable Postgis
RUN service postgresql start \
&& sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
RUN service postgresql stop
```

Comment: I get `Step 5/6 : RUN service postgresql start     && sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;"
 ---> Running in 3116b49b7c86
No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning).
/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c service postgresql start     && sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;"' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: in my case I can use a Django migration to enable the extension https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#createextension

Answer (score 0):

If you see other Dockerfiles using that `psql -c` command, like [`apache/marmotta` Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/marmotta/blob/132542878e931ce5df9793d25f22ca0191fd7802/Dockerfile#L45-L53), you will see lines like:

```
RUN service postgresql start \
    && psql --command "CREATE USER $DB_USER WITH PASSWORD '$DB_PASS';" \
    && psql --command "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME WITH OWNER $DB_USER;"
USER root
RUN service postgresql stop
```

In other words, you need to make sure the postgresql service is running for those commands to succeed.